# C# parallel.foreach starving for data

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

My application processes millions of pieces of data which vary in size.  Small objects are processed quickly while others can take upwards of fifteen minutes.

My current code:

```
List<QueueRecords> queueRecords= Get500QueueRecords();
bool morefiles=true;
while(morefiles)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(
    queueRecords,parallelOptions,(record,loopstate)=>
    {
    //dowork
    }
    queueRecords = Get500QueueRecords();
    if(queueRecords.Count() == 0)
    {
    morefiles = false;
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that many times I will end up with one thread performing a long running task while there are still massive amounts of data to be processed.

Which pattern should I look into to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues: 
   1) `Get500QueueRecords` could also taking some time to execute during which time you aren't doing any processing; 
   2) If the last record in a set takes 15 minutes you are only processing one at a time when it's processing because `ParallelForEach` will be waiting for it to complete.

You really should look at TPL DataFlow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) or at least create a reader Task that's pumping data into a `BlockingCollection<T>` and then launch multiple reader Tasks that pull from the blocking collection until it's consumed.

Using a producer and a consumer with a finite size `BlockingCollection<T>` between them allows you to control (i) how many items are buffered from the reader Task and (ii) how many Tasks you have consuming it.

Comment: Thank you, using a BlockingCollection with Tasks worked beautifully.

Comment: @KevinSmith glad to hear it, please mark this as the answer then.